# AT command : text mode selection doesn't work

Tags: at-command

I want to use SIM800L V2.0 with Arduino Nano in order to send SMS.

I use a SIM card with pin code. I would like to execute these AT commands through serial interface of the Arduino IDE :

```c
at+cpin="xxxx"
at+cmgf=1
AT+CMGS="+33xxxxxxxxx"
my message to sent through SMS<CTRL+Z>
```

I'm blocked at the last command. I don't know why.

I use this code to communicate with the sim800l :

```c
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); 

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (mySerial.available())
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());

  if (Serial.available()) {
    while(Serial.available())
      mySerial.write(Serial.read());

    mySerial.println();
  }
}
```

at+cmgf=1 and AT+CMGS="..." returns "ERROR"

So, I tried to get status of my network connection :

```c
at+cops?
+COPS: 0
```

And, I tried to get a list of all network available :

```c
at+cops=?
+COPS: (1,"Orange F","Orange","20801"),(1,"BOUYGUES TELECOM","BYTEL","20820"),(2,"SFR","SFR","20810"),,(0-4),(0-2)
```

So, have you any ideas to solve this pb ?

Comment: Make sure that the output buffer is flushed after sending `AT+CMGS="+33xxxxxxxxx"`. Can you verify that you see the `> ` prompt from the modem after sending this command? It's important to look at the `OK` and `> ` prompt responses from the modem.

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide you some general tips.

1) Is the device registered?
- Check it by issuing `AT+CREG?` command

```
AT+CREG?
+CREG: 0,N

OK
```

If N=1 your device is registered to the home network. If N=5 you are registered in roaming. Other values of N mean that the registration is ongoing or failed for some reason.

2) Is the Service Center Address set? It's mandatory for MO SMS transmissions.
- Set it by issuing `AT+CSCA=<number>[,<type>]?` command

```
AT+CSCA="+"+33xxxxxxxxx",145
OK
```

`<number>` is the SC of your operator; `<type>` allow you to choose between national numbering scheme (129) and international numbering scheme (145).

3) In debugging phase, try to understand the ERROR cause by switching to *verbose error* mode through `AT+CMEE=2?` command. Then repeat the commands sequence

```
AT+CMEE=2

OK
AT+CMGS="+33xxxxxxxxx"
> Your text<CTRL+Z>

+CME ERROR: <verbose error>
```